# Does sklearn.preprocessing StandardScaler converts the data into standard normal distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing, standardization

`StandardScaler()` from `sklearn.preprocessing` claims to make `mean=0` and `std=1`. In reality, mean is a very small number close to 0 and similarly, std is close to 1 but not equal. Does it really convert the data into standard normal distribution as it uses:

```
z = (x - mu) / sigma
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it out with your Dataset, having different Columns with values having different Ranges.
Scaling using StandardScaler helps in standarization of data, since then calculations for several Distance-Based Algos is better.

Z-Score always converts our particular column into Scaled Data having Mean = 0 and Standard Deviation = 1.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = scaler.fit(X_train)
y_test = model.predict(X_test)
```

Note: Here, I am not applying StandardScaler on y_train, and we shouldn't apply StandardScaler on y data.